# Удаление файлов на поддомене

Tags: php, apache

Здравствуйте!

Имеется основной домен site.ru (с файлами сайта) и поддомен img.site.ru (с изображениями). Их рабочие директории расположены на одном и том же сервере. Есть ли способ удалить файл на поддомене, запуская скрипт удаления на основном домене?

Функция **unlink()** работает только с относительными путями. И кажется только на том домене, на котором был запущен скрипт удаления.

Comment: Вы точно уверены что unlink работает только с относительными путями? На возможность удаления должны влиять только права записи на директорию, из которой удаляете

Comment: Когда вставляю в неё прямую ссылку на файл, выходит следующее предупреждение: "Warning: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking".

Comment: Агааа. Так вы указывайте путь не по http иерархии а относительно корня файловой системы.  Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Нет нет. Удаление производится так: unlink("Хттп://site.com/test.jpg"). Тестирую на локальном сервере Apache. Если удалять вот так: unlink("test.php"), то файл удаляется, но только в случае если производить все операции на одном и том же домене.

Comment: видимо site.com подхватывается http-враппером. Попробуйте unlink('./site.com/test.jpg');

Comment: Добавил сзади ещё одну дополнительную точку, и удаление файла на поддомене прошло успешно. Запись: unlink('../site.com/test.jpg');

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23201/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and-stashappy).

Comment: А вы подумали что если бы `unlink("Хттп://site.com/test.jpg")` работало - то я бы мог удалить все файлы на вашем сайте? И на другом сайте тоже. Вы думаете это безопасно?

Comment: Как обычно сначала подумалось о возможности, а лишь потом о проблемах. Полагаю с вариантом предложенным пользователем "tutankhamun", я могу спать спокойно?

Answer (score 2):

Для ответа на этот вопрос в первую очередь надо понять, что он не имеет смысла.

- Во-первых, **в вебе нет файлов**. А есть только НТТР ресурсы. А НТТР ресурсы удаляются только определенным запросом, и только если он поддерживается.
- Во-вторых, unlink работает только с файлами.

Чтобы понять, чем они отличаются, реромендую прочесть http://phpfaq.ru/paths - сразу станет понятно, что функция unlink работает и с относительными путями, и с абсолютными, но - в **файловой системе**. И если ей передать путь к существующему **файлу**, на который у текущего пользователя есть право удаления, то файл удалится.

То есть, субдомены тут не при чем, а роль играет только расположение в пределах файловой системы

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете "абсолютный путь" и URL.

Если файлы сайтов site.ru и img.site.ru на одном физическом сервере и принадлежат одному пользователю, то файл удалить можно. Мне кажется у вас Денвер, тогда ответ однозначный: да, можно удалить. Только используйте путь в файловой системе, а не URL.